# truncate zeros after the decimal

Tags: c#, sql

I have tried the solutions available on net but couldn't find one that solves my issue.

My question is simple. I have a value in a `Quantity` column:  `120.00`  AS `Decimal(18,2)`

But I do not want to show the zeroes after decimal if there are only zeroes.

Means the required value to show is:  `120`

Looking for the solution either at SQL end or in C#.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try _anything_ to solve your problem first? Have you ever try to format your value? Some your effort first so people might show their.

Comment: `if ( ((int)value) == value )` all zeros?

Comment: Convert the value to **Long** or **Integer**

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you can do:

```
select (cast when quantity = floor(quantity) then cast(floor(quantity) as varchar(255))
             else cast(quantity as varchar(255))
        end)
```

I think this will work in general for decimal types.  Specific SQL engines may have other functions to help.  Oracle, for instance, has `to_char()` and SQL Server has `str()`.

Answer (score 1):

If "show the zeros" is from the point of a C# application (question isn't very clear), then you can use ToString() with a [Custom Numeric Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
myDecimal.ToString("#.##");
```

Will return to two decimal places if there are, but will leave them out if they're all zero

Comment: This would format `120.10` as `120.1`. The question is unclear, but I think the OP wants either two, or zero decimals, never just one.